# Pushing from Eclipse to my GitHub repository via HTTPS stopped working: "git-receive-pack not permitted" error

Tags: git, eclipse, github, egit

I recently did a push to my GitHub repository for a few weeks ago. I got a main from GitHub that GitHub is soon quitting regular authorization and going to replace it with another authorization method.

So today I push a new update to my GitHub repository and got the message:

```
git-receive-pack not permitted
```

That's leads to two questions:

1. Has EGit stopped working now?
2. I have Eclipse 2021-03, how can I fix this issue so I can do a push?

Comment: GitHub has disabled the HTTPS protocol. Use git://... with a SSH key that is known to Eclipse on your local computer and uploaded to your GitHub account instead.

Comment: @howlger Thank you. How can I do that in practice? What should I press on?

Comment: If you do not have a SSH key, in Eclipse go to the preferences _General > Network Connections > SSH2_ tab _Key Management_ and hit _Generate RSA Key..._. In your GitHub account go to _Account settings > SSH and GPG keys_ and add the public key. Finally, change the repository URL from `https://...` to `git://...`.

Comment: @howlger Ok. I have generate the RSA key in Eclipse. I put that key into SSH and GPG keys and add a public key. Is it SSH key or GPG key I should press on?

Comment: This works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-Bcw_6KIbU&ab_channel=Let%27sCodeFaster Please post an answer if you want. I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks. Because you mentioned it, a GPG key is to [signed commits](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/5.3#GPG-signing_Commits).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Since August 13, 2021, **GitHub does not support** authentication via **HTTPS** with your **GitHub account password** for security reasons **anymore**](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-12-git-password-authentication-is-shutting-down/). Instead, in Eclipse, when pushing to a GitHub repository or when fetching from a private repository, you will get a `git-upload-pack not permitted on 'https://github.com...'` error.

As solution, use either

- a GitHub specific **Personal access tokens** as password instead of your previously used GitHub account password or
- **SSH with an SSH key** of which the private and public key is on your local machine and configured in Eclipse and the public key is uploaded to your GitHub account instead.

## Personal access token (GitHub specific)

[image]

1. Go to [your **GitHub account** to ***Settings > Developer settings > Personal access tokens***](https://github.com/settings/tokens) website:

   1. Click the ***Generate new token*** button in the upper right

      - Enter a ***Note***, e.g. `GitHub repo token`
      - Choose ***Expiration***, e.g. ***No expiration***
      - Tick the checkbox ***repo***
   2. Click the ***Generate token*** button at the bottom
   3. **Copy** the generated **token to the clipboard**
2. In Eclipse, in the ***Git Repositories*** view:

   1. **Right-click** the ***Remote**s* sub-**node for GitHub** (`origin` or the name you have chosen when you have cloned the repository) and choose ***Configure Push...***
   2. Click the ***Change...*** button to change the URI in the upper right
   3. **Replace the password with** with the copied generated GitHub **token**
   4. Click ***Finish*** and ***Save*** to apply the changes

## SSH

1. **Create an SSH key** (skip this step when you already have one):

   1. In Eclipse, in the **preferences *General > Network Connections > SSH2*** tab ***Key Management*** hit the ***Generate RSA Key...*** button
   2. Hit ***Save Private Key...*** and choose a location, preferably the subfolder `.ssh` of your user home directory
2. **Upload public key** to your GitHub account:

   1. For a new created key, **copy the string shown in the *Key Management*** tab to the clipboard; for an existing key add it in the preferences *General > Network Connections > SSH2* tab *General* and copy the content of the public key file `<name>.pub`
   2. Go to your [**GitHub account settings** to the ***SSH and GPG keys***](https://github.com/settings/keys) section and hit the ***New SSH key*** button
   3. **Paste** the copied public key into the ***Key*** field
3. **Change HTTPS to SSH URLs** of already cloned repositories:

   1. In Eclipse, in the ***Git Repositories*** view right-click the repository and choose ***Properties*** and click the ***Open*** button
   2. In the text editor of the `config` file change the remote URL as follows:
      **HTTPS** (old; does not work for *push* anymore):

      ```
      url = https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git
      ```

      **SSH** (new):

      ```
      url = git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git
      ```

See also:

- [Video tutorial *Import repository from Github to Eclipse using SSH*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-Bcw_6KIbU)
- [EGit User Guide](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.egit.doc/help/EGit/User_Guide/User-Guide.html)

Comment: For anyone reading this: of course HTTPS works perfectly well: you don't have to switch to SSH if you don't want to.

Comment: @VonC I extended my answer on how to switch to a personal GitHub access token in Eclipse. It would be much nicer and more helpful if you told me that earlier instead of adding your own answer that doesn't say how to do this in Eclipse. If I could, I would give you reputation points for that hint, but unfortunately that's not possible with the way gamification is implemented on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Every new Eclipse install...I visit your answer and it still works!

Comment: For anyone who is still struggling like I was: Install the newer version of Eclipse and try this again. I kept having issues until I upgraded.

Comment: Authentication did not work in my case (Eclipse version 2022-09). I had to enter the PAT as part of the URI: https://<user name>:<PAT>@<repository path>

Comment: on macOS in the git repo in terminal i updated from https to ssh with `git remote set-url origin` and it works in the terminal, however Eclipse can not commit anymore (login rejected), but eclipse worked before and is still correctly set up with ssh.

Comment: @basZero My answer does not say that you should run Git command line commands. Anyway, if you have made such changes outside of Eclipse, do a _Refresh_, e.g. in the _Git Repositories_ view in order to make this change visible in Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger thanks, i did that, but didn't help. Now i noticed that in the terminal, when i switch to ssh based remote origins, it works, but then Eclipse does not work anymore, even when I change the github config in Eclipse from HTTPS PAT mode to SSH2 mode. I also checked the ssh2 config in Eclipse which seems to be correct, it points to the correct ssh directory with the keys...

Comment: @basZero Please ask this as a separate question with showing your config and telling what kind of SSH2 key you use and how you configured it in Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger i wonder whether it is due to my old 2022-version of Eclipse. I'll create a new question if needed. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> GitHub has disabled the HTTPS protocol

Most certainly not.

I push using HTTPS to GitHub without any issue, but I now have to use, as password, a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) instead of the GitHub user account password.

Make sure to create a new token, which will follow the [new token format](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-04-authentication-token-format-updates/) (March 2021)

> `ghp_` for Personal Access Tokens

Answer (score 1):

I was using eclipse and git with ssh and had an issue with it using the wrong key.

When searching for the error: "Cannot log in at github.com:22"
It sent me to this answer: [Cannot log in GitHub into Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68895643/cannot-log-in-github-into-eclipse) which ended up leading me to this one.

For anyone else that stumbles across this you need to navigate to

```
Window -> Preferences
```

Then from there expand

```
General -> Network Connections -> SSH2
```

Then in the right pane select the "General" tab and click the **Add Private Key..** button and select the private key used for git. If you used a password for your key (which you should) then you should be prompted to enter it.

After this I could push and pull again no issues.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an app password or token to import the project from git/bitbucket. This token you need to use as a password.

[image: create app password]

Here create a token by giving the necessary permissions according to your requirements and create it.