# User and Password login pop-up continuously prompt after given while i am trying to import project from github or committing to github in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, github

Steps :

1 . Browse File > import
2. Git> Project from Git(with smart import)
3. Clone URI
4. Providing all details on "Source Git Repository" pop-up(Location, Connection as https , Authentication) and click Next.
5. Prompt login page.

i am facing same pop-up while trying to commit to github.

[image]

Comment: you can create a `ssh` key for your local machine with GitHub and with that you can do git operations by providing your password only, https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802292/6505250

Comment: thank you by using ssh now i am able to import project. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Github has decommissioned 'username-password' based authentication since August 13, 2021. Now only token based authentication is allowed.
You would need to set up personal token in your git account and use that in IDE.

This link could be useful:
https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/admin/authentication/authenticating-users-for-your-github-enterprise-server-instance/changing-authentication-methods