# Getting Can't connect to any URI (not authorized) error while pushing the commit to github repo

Tags: eclipse, github, git-commit

I'm simply trying to push my practice project code (from eclipse) to the github public repo. But unable to do so as it say **Can't connect to any URI (not authorized) error**
Is generating the ssh key is mandatory?
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVXd3.jpg)

Comment: You have to use either a _personal access token_ as password (instead of your GitHub account password) or SSH key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802292/6505250

Comment: I can able to push the code to the repository via ssh key method.
Thank you @howlger :)