# EGIT Can't connect to any repository - Missing unknown

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I just created a new repository on GitHub and trying to initially push my local Java project.
I added the ssh key in my GitHub account, and it's referenced correctly by Eclipse, I assume.

I only get this error message when I'm trying to push:

```
Can't connect to any repository:
git@github.com:MaximStein/MyProject.git
(git@github.com:MaximStein/MyProject.git: Missing unknown
366362as232d670123a2267b4879bbd01d142426)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does that project exist under that account? You can't push there until it does.

Comment: Did you follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802292/6505250)? Do you have only one GitHub project or is this for all your GitHub projects?

Comment: Which EGit/JGit version do you have? There was an issue causing _Missing unknown_, error, but that has been fixed four years ago: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470318

Comment: @Maxim Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Typically this occurs when you edit or amend your commit before first push to a remote.  If this is the case, instead of amending the first commit, simply delete the .git folder from repo folder and execute git init again. Add your remote with git remote add and make sure you create and update the .gitignore before trying to commit. I came across this multiple times when large files prevented me from trying to push my first commit, forcing me to amend my commit.

Answer (score 2):

Your **Git repository** seems to be **broken or** at least **in an invalid state**.

The root cause seems to be `Missing unknown 366362as232d670123a2267b4879bbd01d142426` which means something (probably the HEAD) points to the object with the hash 366362as232d670123a2267b4879bbd01d142426 (which will be stored in the file `.git/objects/36/6362as232d670123a2267b4879bbd01d142426`) that does not exist.

In the ***Git History*** you might **right-click** the **last commit** and choose ***Reset > Soft (HEAD Only)***. If commits are missing, you might be able to recover them via the *Git Reflog* view.

Make also sure your Eclipse and EGit/JGit is up to date (for instance, [there was an issue causing a *Missing unknown* error that has been fixed more than four years ago](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470318)) and that you do a refresh (<kbd>F5</kbd>) in Eclipse after you have executed Git operations on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try first if the push would succeed from command line (which means you need in to install Git first):

- check you are correctly identified with `ssh -Tv git@github.com`
- check your remote origin URL: `git remote -v`
- check your local status (`git status`: to make sure you are on a branch, here I assume main, and that you have made at least one commit)
- check your initial push: `git push -u origin main`

Check also if you have declared any submodules (`.gitmodules` file), or look for any nested Git repository (`.git` subfolder anywhere beside your repository root folder)

It is helpful to rule out (or not) a git-core issue, before investigation an Egit/JGit one.

And the [OP Maxim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15501126/maxim) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69622786/egit-cant-connect-to-any-repository-missing-unknown/69625995#comment123068746_69625995):

> It's a good idea to try it in the command line first.
>
> It says "`fatal: bad object HEAD`" when I do `git status`.
> I think I've only made one local commit for that project.

Indeed, making local commits, in a branch, is a prerequisite to pushing anything.
In your case, do a `git branch -avv` to check if there are any.

If you already pushed that missing commit, assuming your main branch is `main` (not `master`):

```
git fetch origin
git reset --soft origin/main
```

Comment: You answer does not work for me: `'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.

Comment: @howlger Yes, it does suppose you have Git installed (since Eclipse, through Egit, is using JGit, and does not rely on Git directly)

Comment: Your answer does not make sense for EGit/JGit. `ssh -Tv git@github.com` might fail while it works with EGit and vice versa, etc. It is not helpful to answer EGit questions as if they would be git-core questions.

Comment: @howlger First, check if the issue persists from command line. Then go back to the IDE. That is how I would troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: If it works on the command line doesn't mean it will work in EGit and vice versa.

Comment: It's a good idea to try it in the command line first. It says "fatal: bad object HEAD" when I do git status. I think I've only made one local commit for that project.

Comment: @Maxim Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC The addition looks passive-aggressive to me.

Comment: @howlger I am sincerely sorry, that was not the intention. Feel free to edit the answer and include your opinion much better than I could.

Comment: @VonC Please remove it. I don't understand what you mean by _"Indeed, making local commits, in a branch, is a prerequisite to pushing anything."_ It was said that one local commit was made. How to push nothing in EGit?