# Git https push with user/password not working in STS4

Tags: git, eclipse, github

When I try to push it asks for a username and password. Even when the credentials are correct, I am not able to push.

I have not installed the CLI to config.

I have not enabled 2-factor for git.

I have tried increasing the timeout.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68790276/2670892) answer you question? Github don't support username + password authentication anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y**ou can’t push code to GitHub with a simple username and password anymore.
Instead of a password to authenticate, GitHub now requires a personal access token instead.**

To generate a personal access token in GitHub and fix the ‘support for password authentication removed’ error, follow these steps:

1. Log into GitHub with your username and password
2. Navigate to your GitHub account settings
3. Scroll down and click ‘Developer settings’ in the list of links to the left
4. Click the Personal access tokens link
5. Click the ‘Generate new token’ button
6. Add a ‘Note’ to describe the tokens usage
7. Set an expiration date for the GitHub personal access token
8. Select the appropriate authentication scope
9. Click the ‘Generate token’ button