# Connect Eclipse to Github

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I am setting up eclipse and connecting to Github. However, eclipse would not let me push and commit. Whenever I try doing that, eclipse asks me to sign in (using Github password) multiple times and shows me this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwKYv.png) when I cancel the sign-in request. I followed this video exactly and cannot pass the sign-in step. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPT7v69guVY
Could anyone help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: In the future, please [do not link code or pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) when you post questions. Just copy and paste the text directly into your post.

Comment: Github no longer allows just using a password, see the duplicate for how to connect now.

Comment: @MarsAtomic This question is a duplicate, but of a different question (using Github password has been disabled not that long): https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802292/6505250