# Unable to clone GitHub repo in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I have EGit 5.11.1 plugin installed in Eclipse Luna 4.4.2.
I'm trying to clone my private GitHub repository in Eclipse using the HTTPS URI.
Getting the below error. I have configured HTTPS.sslVerify and HTTP.sslVerify as false as suggested in some other posts. I'm not using any proxy server
[image]

Also, the git clone of the same URL above works fine from git bash and strangely does not even ask for the user name password.

Comment: In case you use your GitHub account password for your Git repository which does not work anymore since August 13, 2021: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802292/6505250 By the way, your Eclipse is pretty outdated, please upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @howlger. It did work with PAT. However, I still do not understand why Git bash was able to clone the repo without personal access token. I had some old credentials stored in Windows Credentials, and even when I changed my github password, Git bash was able to clone the repo. Only today, when I manually removed the password from Windows credential manager did it give the below error asking me to use personal access token and also prompted to sign in to github.

Comment: Cloning and fetching a public GitHub repository via HTTPS does not require authentication.