# eclipse egit: login window pops up and rejects my credentials

Tags: git, eclipse, github, egit, git-authentication

I'm trying to push some changes to my repository (after quite some time) and the login window pops up. The credentials I'm putting are correct (they correspond to my user that has access to the private repository), but eclipse rejects them anyway. [image]

I thought this was deprecated. How can I fix this?

Comment: Github requires you to use a PAT rather than just a password now. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68790276/2670892)

Comment: thanks! solved by personal access tokens