# EGit authentication failed

Tags: eclipse, egit

I'm using *Eclipse 2020-12*, I have cloned a project from my *github* repo to my local hd.
I open it with Eclipse, the project is correctly recognized but everything I do with egit (pull, synchronize, push) it ask me to login. Even if I insert the correct user and pass the login fail. With bash everything works fine. I have tried with *Windows Credential Manager*, with *eclipse -> windows -> preference -> security -> content -> delete all* but nothing works.

P.S.: I don't have two factor auth on my github

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68790276/2670892)

Comment: Thanks man, I will try as soon as possible and let you know.

Comment: If you used the password of your GitHub account, it is what greg-449 said.

Comment: works like a charms! Thanks