# Git login in eclipse not possible

Tags: eclipse, egit

I want to import a project from an existing git repository in Eclipse via URI. The Problem is that my git password and user are not accepted. I double checked username and password multiple times but nothing happens.

Anyone an idea why this happens?

Comment: Where is your project stocked?

Comment: If  the project is on github see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68790276/2670892) You need to use a Personal Access Token

Comment: PAT worked! Thank you @greg-449!!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem while pushing to GitHub.
*The error was Can't connect to any repository: https://github.com/~ ([https://github.com/~](https://github.com/%7E): not authorized)* Seem the error relates to Eclipse not getting authorized.
Instead I turned to Git bash and it worked. *I recommend using Git Bash*.

Comment: No, it's related to GitHub not accepting the password of the user account anymore. It's the same on Git bash. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802292/6505250