# Eclipse/Liclipse Git connection "not authorized"

Tags: eclipse, egit, liclipse

Windows 10, various installs of LiClipse/Eclipse.

Attempting to clone a git via HTTPS from github or gitlab.

Error:  "(url of git): not authorized

An error occurred when trying to contact (https URL).  See the error log for more details

Possible reasons:

- Incorrect URL
- No network connection (e.g., wrong proxy settings)
- SSL host could not be verified (set http.sslVerify=false in Git configuration)"

Using any of:

- Fresh install of LiClipse
- Fresh install of eclipse for PHP with PyDev and EGit added
- Old install of LiClipse, updated from within the program, that was working before but is now getting the same error on a git that it was able to sync with before

In both cases, "Fresh install" means "installer downloaded from the web at time of install, installed on a machine that had its C: drive formatted last week, with Windows reinstalled from the latest microsoft image".  Have updated to the latest level of the software using Help->Check for Updates.

User/password works on the web.

Only google hit I've found on this says to delete the password in the secure store and try again.  On the fresh installs, the secure store was empty.  On the old machine, it didn't help.

Comment: For github you must use a PAT not a password - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68790276/2670892)

Answer (score 0):

Per comment from greg-449:

Github no longer lets you use your password, you have to create a personal access token here:

https://github.com/settings/tokens

You use that instead of your password.