# Import Existing Project from Github in to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github

I have created a simple Cucumber / Selenium Automation project in Eclipse and uploaded it to Github.

I would like to use it to create another similar project but testing a different website. I am trying to figure out how to import it into Eclipse but am running int to issues as I really don't know which options to select when importing.

So I select option Git > Project from Git >  Clone URI > Enter Git URI and click Next > Next on Branch selection >

So in local destination step I have error saying "C:\Users\user\git\CucumberAutomationFramework is not an empty directory. So then I Change the name for my new project to NF_CucumberAutomationFramework

So next step is 'Select a Wizard ...' with import as new project as default selection.

So I click 'Finish' then Java project.

So then I enter  a name for the new project (which I though I had already above) Then click Finish.

But then I get the below error ..

```
Connecting Git team provider failed. See log for details.
Connecting Git team provider failed. See log for details.
Error connecting project NF_CucumberAutomationFramework, no Git repositories found
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? This is so frustrating! Do I need to just clone it using the command line and then use the import from File System option. I'm going to keep playing around and try different options.

My Eclipse is ...

Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)
Build id: 20211202-1639

Comment: Are you using a PAT for github? They no longer allow user + password - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802292/2670892)

Comment: I just get the same error. I wasn't even entering my git username and password before. I did this time but token instead of password, but still get the same error.

Comment: Does the error message `:\Users\user\git\CucumberAutomationFramework is not an empty directory` really starts with `:`? The recommended way is just drop the GitHub project website onto your Eclipse and to use smart import instead of using the new Java project wizard. Or in the _Git Repositories_ view, first clone the repository and then right-click the cloned repository and choose _Import Projects..._ Could you please try the second and than tell what you get after which step? By the way, it is frustrating to hear that you are frustrated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by drop the Github project website into your eclipse. Not entering the URI in the Source GIT Repository section? I've tried both Projects from GIT and Projects from GIT (with smart import) but they just appear to be the same. And sorry it was 'C:\Users\user\git\CucumberAutomationFramework is not an empty directory. I was mucking around so much that somehow I managed to get a new project, I think this was from just downloading the zip and importing from file system. Its frustrating to hear that you are frustrated about me being frustrated but thanks for the help.

Comment: I cloned the repository, but when I try to import it, it doesn't appear to do anything. Project not added to project explorer. I refreshed eclipse.

Comment: When you drag a GitHub project link (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/eclipse/tm4e)) onto the title bar of your Eclipse IDE window, the pre-filled clone dialog opens and all you have to do is press _Finish_. If you tried open projects with a wizard before, you first have to do a hard reset (in the _Git Repositories_ view right-click the repository and choose _Reset..._). At what point exactly are you stuck now?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I've not gone though all the steps, but I feel like this just gets me to the same point I got to when I tried import from Git. I'll need to give it a proper go later. Thanks will report back.