# How to connect eclipse with github?

Tags: eclipse, github

I am trying to connect eclipse to GitHub. I did the suggested steps to do that but I always get the same error as in the following picture:
[image]

Any suggestion please?

Notes:

1. I have the same URL
2. No proxy on my computer
3. `.git` is not missing
4. SSH... I dont know what is it?

Comment: Are you using a PAT to access github, they no longer accept a userid + password - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802292/2670892)

Comment: What does the error log actually say?

Comment: @greg-449 what do you mean by PAT.

Comment: PAT - Personal Access Token, see the link

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you used `https://github.com/.../annotation.git:` as location URI. But the location URI has to end with `.git`, not with `.git:`. Just delete the colon `:` at the end in the *Clone Git Repository* dialog in the first field *URI*.

Comment: no it was not the error, i still get the same error after  i delete the :

Comment: Well, `:` is an error, but there might be more. For example, if it is a private repository, you have to specify a valid user and personal access token as password (not your GitHub account password).