# git-receive-pack not permitted while pushing the code from eclipse to GitHub with access token

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, github, azure-devops

I was facing issue even I have entered correct username & password[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeL5D.png) while pushing the code from eclipse to git.

I have generated access token instated of password then trying to add files to git through eclipse. Again I have facing below issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsyh1.png)

please can anyone help me.

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What is the scope of your personal access token and has it not yet expired? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802292/6505250

Comment: Please take a look at River's answer and howlger's suggestions to see if they are helpful to you. If you think it is a solution, please mark it as a correct answer. Others who meet the same question will appreciate you much.

Answer (score 0):

there are some aspects you can think;

1. network is OK? try to invite the github address directly to make sure your network is OK.
2. sure you get link to the code lab
   you have use
   `git init`
   `git remote add origin ...(your code lab address)`
   or you get the code from `git clone ..address`